# Remove all occurences of an element in a Linked List using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, linked-list

I'm making the implementation of the Linked-List data structure and I'm looking foward to implement a `remove` method of all the occurrences of an element using recursion, here's a piece of my code:

```
public class MyLinkedList<T> {
  private Node<T> head;
  private Node<T> last;
  private int length;

  public void remove(T elem) {
    if (!(this.isContained(elem)) || this.isEmpty())
      return;
    else {
      if (head.value.equals(elem)) {
        head = head.next;
        length--;
        remove(elem);
      } else {
        // This is a constructor which requieres a head and last, and a length
        new MyLinkedList<>(head.next, last, length-1).remove(elem);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I do understand the problem, I'm working with copies of a list not with the original, so, how could I merge or make this sub to the original list?

Comment: Um... `private int long;`? `public void void(...)`?  You may want to go back and review some Java fundamentals (like that `long` and `void` are reserved keywords that can't be used as names of things, before tackling anything so ambitious as a doubly-linked list...

Comment: K... in the actual code it's called 'longitud' a word in Spanish, I'm just being friendly with monolingual speakers, don't worry In a few seconds I'll make edit, and with the double `void` it was my bad when I was writing the code in Stack. I do not use Stack a lot as you can see with my 10 reputation account. adding a note, is a one-way linked list, so I hope you learn to have a more comprehensive reading before you make misjudged and not useful comments.

Comment: My humble apologies for not seeing the bigger picture.  Now, do you _really need_ to ignore the straightforward linear solution to this problem and solve it with recursion instead?

Comment: Unfortunately I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I *had* to do it with recursion, I think it would look something like this:

```
public void remove(T elem)
{
    removeHelper(null, this.head, elem);
}

private void removeHelper(Node<T> prev, Node<T> head, T elem)
{
    if (head != null) {
        if (head.value.equals(elem)) {
            if (head == this.head) {
                this.head = head.next;
            } else {
                prev.next = head.next;
            }
            if (this.last == head) {
                this.last = prev;
            }
            --this.length;
        } else {
            prev = head;
        }
        removeHelper(prev, head.next, elem);
    }
}
```

For the record, if I *didn't* have to use recursion, I'd do it linearly like this:

```
private void remove(T elem)
{
    Node<T> prev = null;
    Node<T> curr = this.head;
    while (curr != null) {
        if (curr.value.equals(elem)) {
            if (this.last == curr) {
                this.last = prev;
            }
            if (prev == null) {
                this.head = curr.next;
            } else {
                prev.next = curr.next;
            }
            --this.length;
        } else {
            prev = curr;
        }
        curr = curr.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider a list like 5,0,1,2,5,5,3,4,5 if I want to delete de element 5. Considering the 5th and 6th elements of the list, some of these 5 will be pointed by the previous reference, instead of 2, which is the reference wished. So, making a little modification in the recursive solution, consider re-asing the previous reference manually and then call the method using `prev` instead `head`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing this in a separate static function instead of doing it in the actual node class since you are recursing through the entire linked list.

```
public void removeAllOccurences(Node<T> head, Node<T> prev, T elem) {
    if (head == null) {
      return;
    }
    if (head.value.equals(elem)) {
      Node<T> temp = head.next;
      if (prev  != null) {
        prev.next = temp;
      }
      head.next = null; // The GC will do the rest.
      removeAllOccurences(temp, prev, elem);
    } else {
      removeAllOccurences(head.next, head, elem);
    }
  }
```